# Clojure: put file of strings into integer array

Tags: clojure

Using clojure, how do you read a file of strings and store it in an int-array or vector.

Here are my functions so far.

```
(:require [clojure.java.io :as io])
 (defn getData [filename]
   (doseq [line
     (with-open [rdr (io/reader filename)]
       (doall (line-seq rdr)))]
         (println line)))

(defn convert [string]
  (map #(Integer/parseInt %)
    (.split #" " string)))
```

I am not sure where to go from here. I have tried to call the getData function inside the convert function but have had no luck because the getData function is not returning the string.

```
-> (apply convert (getData "num.txt"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read some more about clojure and perhaps go over some exercises like the ones in [4clojure](https://www.4clojure.com/) to sharpen your understanding a little. Your attempt is very confused, and I am not sure you understand what every line does there.

Essentially, you are looing over all lines with `doseq` and printing them to the screen, which returns `nil`. Then you try to apply convert to `nil`. You should do fine just returning the result of `doall`.

As for your `convert` function, you are trying to split a list of strings, you should map `split` over the list first, and call `parseInt` on the results of that. You shouldnt need to invoke it using `apply`, instead treat the argument as a list of strings, and it will make a little more sense.

Answer (score 0):

First, how is your file ?

I assume it is like that

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
```

First you want to parse a line into a collection of integers (str/split is from clojure.string) :

```
(defn parse-line [str-line]
  (->> (str/split str-line #" " )
       (map #(Integer/parseInt %))))
```

Then you want to apply this to all lines an return a big array (java array ?) of integers :

```
(defn getData [filename]
  (with-open [rdr (io/reader filename)]
    (let [data (line-seq rdr)]
      (int-array (mapcat parse-line data)))))
```

If you want to have separate arrays

```
(defn getData [filename]
  (with-open [rdr (io/reader filename)]
    (let [data (line-seq rdr)]
      (doall (map (comp int-array parse-line) data)))))
```

Line-seq returns a sequence of lines. So even if you ad one line, line-seq will return a sequence containing your single line. 
If you want vector(s), just replace int-array by vec. For sequence(s), remove int-array.